# Plugging values into ModelForm fields at __init__ time

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

I want to add `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` fields to the UserProfile admin page. So you can change all the user's details from within the UserProfile admin instead of having to go to a different page to change email and some other fields.

This is what my custom form looks like:

```
class CustomProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
        super(CustomProfileForm, self).__init__(*a, **k)
        self.user_instance = None
        if self.instance:
            self.user_instance = self.instance.user

    def clean_first_name(self):
        self.user_instance.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']

    def clean_first_name(self):
        self.user_instance.last_name = self.cleaned_data['laset_name']

    def clean(self):
        self.user_instance.save()
        return self.cleaned_data

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomProfileForm
```

I don't know what to do to complete this. I need to give the `user_instance` details to the proper form class.

Answer (score 2):

To set the initial values in the init method you can use the fields dictionary.

```
def __init__(self, *a, **k):
    # < snip >
    self.fields[ 'email' ].initial = self.user_instance.email
    # ... and any others
```

Comment: What I mean is to have the user's email, last name, and first name get added into the text boxes when the form is displayed. Currently only info from the UserProfile object gets added to bound forms. I need to add data from the `Userprofile.user` instance.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't combine your title with the body of your question.  Edited.